# Get iframe name with Vbscript

Tags: vbscript

How do I extract the iframe name with vbscript? like for example if my string value is

```
<DIV style="MARGIN-TOP: 0px; WIDTH: 670px; HEIGHT: 210px; VISIBILITY: visible; MARGIN-LEFT: -335px; TOP: 48px" id=TB_window><DIV id=TB_title>  <DIV id=TB_ajaxWindowTitle>Add Media</DIV>  <DIV id=TB_closeAjaxWindow><A id=TB_closeWindowButton title=Close href="#" jQuery172014112867239284427="140"><IMG src="http://www.gorgeoushentai.com/wp-includes/js/thickbox/tb-close.png"></A></DIV></DIV><IFRAME style="WIDTH: 670px; HEIGHT: 180px" id=TB_iframeContent onload=tb_showIframe() src="http://www.gorgeoushentai.com/wp-admin/media-upload.php?post_id=168&amp;" frameBorder=0 name=TB_iframeContent656 hspace=0>This feature requires inline frames. You have iframes disabled or your browser does not support them.</IFRAME></DIV>
```

Then the extracted value would be **TB_iframeContent656**

I attempted to write the code in vbscript but it doesn't work

```
<script type="text/vbscript">
box="<DIV style=""MARGIN-TOP: 0px; WIDTH: 670px; HEIGHT: 210px; VISIBILITY: visible; MARGIN-LEFT: -335px; TOP: 48px"" id=TB_window><DIV id=TB_title>  <DIV id=TB_ajaxWindowTitle>Add Media</DIV>  <DIV id=TB_closeAjaxWindow><A id=TB_closeWindowButton title=Close href=""#"" jQuery172014112867239284427=""140""><IMG src=""http://www.gorgeoushentai.com/wp-includes/js/thickbox/tb-close.png""></A></DIV></DIV><IFRAME style=""WIDTH: 670px; HEIGHT: 180px"" id=TB_iframeContent onload=tb_showIframe() src=""http://www.gorgeoushentai.com/wp-admin/media-upload.php?post_id=168&amp;"" frameBorder=0 name=TB_iframeContent656 hspace=0>This feature requires inline frames. You have iframes disabled or your browser does not support them.</IFRAME></DIV>"

data = box.document.getElementById("TB_iframeContent").name
document.write(data)
</script>
```

Comment: Try `document.getElementById("TB_iframeContent").name`

Comment: can you help me write the code. I added my code in the first post

Answer (score 0):

There are two things wrong with your code:

1. A `string` object doesn't contain a value/method named document.
2. When you execute it like this the code will be executed before the document is created so stuff like the iframe won't exist yet, so obviously such an element can't be found.

Look at the code below for a working example. First of all it will look at the actual page instead of a `string`. The `WindowLoad` function makes sure the page is loaded before executing the code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/vbscript">
Set window.onload = GetRef("WindowLoad")
Function WindowLoad
    Dim somediv
    Set somediv = document.getElementById("someid")

    Dim data 
    Set data = document.getElementById("TB_iframeContent")
    if data Is Nothing then
        MsgBox("element does not exist")
    else
        somediv.InnerHTML = data.name
    end if

End Function
</script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Some ID for testing purposes -->
<div id="someid"></div>
<!-- The DIV with the iframe -->
<div style="MARGIN-TOP: 0px; WIDTH: 670px; HEIGHT: 210px; VISIBILITY: visible; MARGIN-LEFT: -335px; TOP: 48px" id=TB_window>
    <div id=TB_title>  
    <div id=TB_ajaxWindowTitle>Add Media</DIV>  
    <DIV id=TB_closeAjaxWindow><A id=TB_closeWindowButton title=Close href="#" jQuery172014112867239284427="140">
        <IMG src="http://www.gorgeoushentai.com/wp-includes/js/thickbox/tb-close.png"></A>
    </DIV>
    </DIV>
    <IFRAME style="WIDTH: 670px; HEIGHT: 180px" id=TB_iframeContent onload=tb_showIframe() src="http://www.gorgeoushentai.com/wp-admin/media-upload.php?post_id=168&amp;" frameBorder=0 name=TB_iframeContent656 hspace=0>This feature requires inline frames. You have iframes disabled or your browser does not support them.</IFRAME>
    </DIV>
</body>
</html>
```